# How to pass a JavaScript object already on the page in to an AngularJS template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a KendoUI grid on my page bound to a JavaScript array. When a row in the grid is clicked the row change event fires and I grab the object representing that row. I now want to use AngularJS's templating to bind to that model like this...

```
<div ng-app ng-model="currentRecord">
  {{FirstName}} - {{Surname}}
</div>
```

Both FirstName and Surname are properties on the object for the row. So I guess what I'm asking is how do I set the model from outside of an AngularJs controller?

I'm only just picking Angular up so what I'm asking may be a bad idea, if that's the case please let me know why.

**Update**

As per Pieter's answer I've tried to achieve this with "Angular Kendo"

I'm using the MVC helpers to render the grid and my code looks like this

```
<div ng-app="ngUsers">
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
        <div class="span6">
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                  .Name("Grid")

                  .Columns(columns =>
                      {
                          columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden(true);
                          columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
                          columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
                      })
                  .Groupable()
                  .Pageable()
                  .Sortable()
                  .Scrollable()
                  .Filterable()
                  .Selectable()
                  .Events(e => e.Change("rowSelected"))
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                .Ajax()
                                                .Read(read => read.Action("AjaxList", "User"))
                  )
                  )
        </div>

        <div id="results">
            {{FirstName}}   
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is for when a row is selected the firstname property in that object is shown in the results div.

My angular controller looks like this....

```
var ngUsers = angular.module('ngUsers', ["kendo.directives"]);

ngUsers.controller("UserCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.rowSelected = function (kendoEvent) {
        var grid = kendoEvent.sender;
        var selectedRow = grid.select();
        $scope.user = selectedRow;
    }; 
});
```

This gives me rowSelected is not defined on the line that binds the grid change event. I assume this is because the grid can't see the rowSelected event in the angular controller?

Comment: JSON is a protocol for representing JavaScript objects as strings. Perhaps you mean JavaScript array and JavaScript object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes. Normally ng-model is used on inputs, but in your case we can use it as a marker to link angular world with non-angular world.

```
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-model="currentRecord" ng-show="currentRecord">
  {{currentRecord.FirstName}} - {{currentRecord.Surname}}
</div>
```

ng-model only binds to a javascript object on the current scope, so if you need to access properties from it you need to reference it directly.

Updating the model from an external(not angular) source

```
function myExternalFunction() {
    //external code
    // we need to get the element and wrap it in an angular element
    var $element = angular.element('[ng-model="currentRecord"]');
    var scope = $element.scope();
    //the ngModel controller will have the correct apis
    var ngModelController = $element.controller('ngModel');

    //the external data
    var model = {'FirstName' : 'John', 'Surname': 'Smith'};

    //$apply to notify angular that the models have changed from outside
    scope.$apply(function() {
      //$viewValue is only useful for inputs not divs.
      ngModelController.$viewValue = model;
      //this will actually set the value on the scope
      ngModelController.$setViewValue(model);
    });
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Dcda0ROjP4IEkizDALj?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Angular Kendo](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo) ? Have a look at [The data source example](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/datasource). You have to add an attribute to the div:

```
on-change="rowSelected(kendoEvent)"
```

and then you need to define a function in a controller:

```
$scope.rowSelected = function(kendoEvent) {
   var grid = kendoEvent.sender;
   var selectedRows = grid.select();
   ...
}
```

If you don't know how to define a controller and use it in your HTML, take a look at [this quick video](http://www.egghead.io/video/MEmC0QH8ATQ).